# how to avoid re-definition web component in lit-element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class MyPublic extends LitElement {
  render(){
    return html`
        <p>A paragraph</p>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-public', MyPublic);
```

I defined a public web component like that in `MyPublic.js`. And then when I need to use it in `FooComponent.js`, I will import `MyPublic.js`, when I need to use it in `BarComponent.js`, I will also import `MyPublic.js`. It will cause re-definition for `my-public`.

How to avoid it?

Just import all the web components in `index.js`, and then don't import it anymore?

Comment: The last I heard `import` is only supposed to load each file once.

Answer (score 2):

No, this will not cause a re-definition of your element, the same way your final (live) JavaScript code in the browser doesn't contain a dozen copies of the LitElement or Polymer library.

Imports are de-duped by the browser's runtime. This implies that global variables defined in a module also exist only once in memory, and more generally that free code in modules is only executed once.

You can read more about this [in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule). But essentially:

> This [import] operation must be idempotent if it completes normally. Each time it is called with a specific referencingScriptOrModule, specifier pair as arguments it must return the same Module Record instance.